# Copy files with same extensions in the same directory to another directory - Python

Tags: python, directory, copy

I have some files in the same directory which have the same extension(.html). Those files need to all be copied to another directory. I've looked up documentations on both `shutil` and `os` but couldn't find any proper answer...

I have some pseudo codes as below:

```
import os, shutil

copy file1, file2, file3 in C:\abc
to C:\def
```

If anyone knows how to solve this, pls let me know. Appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I created this script for sorting files in a folder. try it.

```
import glob
import os

#get list of file 
orig = glob.glob("G:\\RECOVER\\*")

dest = "G:\\RECOVER_SORTED\\"

count = 0

#recursive function through all the nested folders
def smista(orig,dest):
    for f in orig:
            #split filename at the last point and take the extension
            if f.rfind('.') == -1:
                #in this case the file is a folder
                smista(glob.glob(f+"\\*"),dest)
            else:
                #get extension
                ext = f[f.rfind('.')+1:]

                #if the folder does not exist create it
                if not os.path.isdir(dest+ext):
                    os.makedirs(dest+ext)
                global count
                os.rename(f,dest+ext+"\\"+str(count)+"."+ext)
                count = count+1
#if the destination path does not exist create it            
if not os.path.isdir(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest)

smista(orig,dest)
input("press close to exit")
```

Comment: you should use os.join.path rather than "+"

Answer (score 0):

[assuming python3, but should be similiar in 2.7]

you can use [listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) from os and [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) from shutil:

```
import os, shutil, os.path

for f in listdir("/path/to/source/dir"):
    if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == "html":
        shutil.copy(f, "/path/to/target/dir")
```

warning: this is scrapped together without testing. corrections welcome

edit (cause i can't comment):
@ryan9025 `splitext` is from`os.path`, my bad.

Comment: I run this codes with modified paths, but it returns `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'splitext'`? I use python 3.6 and I'm pretty sure it has `splitext`

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an correct answer by myself with a combinations of all the replies.

So if I have a python script in (a) directory, all the source files in (b) directory, and the destination is in (c) directory.

Below is the correct code that should work, and it looks very neat as well.

```
import os
import shutil
import glob

src = r"C:/abc"
dest = r"C:/def"

os.chdir(src)
for files in glob.glob("*.html"):
        shutil.copy(files, dest)
```